# Using the GeoIP module with Nginx and UWSGI

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi, geoip

I am trying to integrate this module but its a little beyond me:

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpGeoipModule

In my nginx config I have this:

```
geoip_country /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat;
```

I added it to the build options and included in libraries needed to use it and this all seems to be fine. I am working with Python running on Nginx and UWSGI and I have no idea about the next step to actually retrieve the result of the geoip on my page.

I posted this on the nginx message board with no luck so if anyone can give me any help at all I would really appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you can set nginx to pass GeoIP data into your CGI app via custom HTTP headers, e.g.:

```
proxy_set_header X-GeoIP-Country $geoip_country_name;
proxy_set_header X-GeoIP-City    $geoip_city;
```

CGI application will receive these custom headers along with standard HTTP headers provided by client-side.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. In my case, is my CGI app UWSGI?

Comment: @user1738522 Yes, in your case it is UWSGI, though the method will work for any CGI application. The only note is that the example above assumes that nginx and CGI application are linked via tcp-sockets (i.e. **proxy_pass** nginx directive is used to pass data to the CGI app). If you are using FastCGI protocol directly (i.e. **fastcgi_pass** nginx directive is used), then the code should be like: `fastcgi_param GeoIP_Country $geoip_country_name;
fastcgi_param GeoIP_City $geoip_city;`

Comment: **uWSGI** usually uses `uwsgi` protocol, then that must be `uwsgi_param`.

Comment: i'm always getting undefined when calling req.headers['X-GeoIP-Country'] , i use express node js  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51265803/nginx-proxy-set-header-does-not-pass-req-header-to-backend-undefined-req-heade